# lxml fails to extract all text when nested elements are present?

Tags: python, lxml

I am parsing some large xml files, with the goal of extracting all raw text contained under the `body` element. I don't in which sub-elements the text occurs - I'm just concatenating all the text.

The relevant bit of code I'm using to achieve this is:

```
# find all instances of `body`
result = []
for body in tree.findall('.//{*}body'): 
    # iterate recursively over all sub-elemetns of `body`
    for node in body.iter('*'):
        # append any text if it exists
        if node.text:
            # handle the text
            result.append(node.text.strip())
print(' '.join(result))
```

Pretty straightforward, and I *thought* it was working, but I've found some cases where it's failing that I'm not sure how to work around. Here's a minimal example extracted from an xml file:

```
<cja:body>
  <ce:sections xmlns:ce=".../xml/common/schema">
    <ce:para view="all">For scyptolin A or B the IC
                <ce:inf loc="post">50</ce:inf> was erroneously calculated at 3.1 μg/ml. The correct IC
                <ce:inf loc="post">50</ce:inf> was determined at 0.16 μg/ml for both scyptolins.
            </ce:para>
  </ce:sections>
</cja:body>
```

If I run the above code block on this xml, the output is:

```
For scyptolin A or B the IC 50 50
```

So the problem is, for the `para` node, `node.text` only seems to retrieve text that occurs *before* the nested `inf` element. How do I extract all the text, not just that occurring before nested elements? To be clear, the desired output here would be:

```
For scyptolin A or B the IC 50 was erroneously calculated at 3.1 μg/ml. The correct IC 50 was determined at 0.16 μg/ml for both scyptolins.
```

Comment: Ah, looks like I'm looking for the `.tail` attribute, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701546/how-to-extract-text-in-nested-xml-after-closing-of-one-tag-in-python-using-xml-e)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701546/how-to-extract-text-in-nested-xml-after-closing-of-one-tag-in-python-using-xml-e), but I'll answer here for completeness.

It turns out I need to use the `.tail` attribute of the `inf` element to get the text following it (which was a surprise...I thought the text would still be attribute of the `para` element). Thus the fixed code would be:

```
result = []
for body in tree.findall('.//{*}body'): 
    # iterate recursively over all sub-elemetns of `body`
    for node in body.iter('*'):
        # append any text if it exists
        if node.text:
            result.append(node.text.strip())
        # NEW! add `node.tail` if present:
        if node.tail:
            result.append(node.tail.strip())
print(' '.join(result))
```

Which yields

```
For scyptolin A or B the IC 50 was erroneously calculated at 3.1 μg/ml. The correct IC 50 was determined at 0.16 μg/ml for both scyptolins.
```

as desired.